# storing and retrieving corrdinates using jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I want to use jsPlumb (with jquery) to create a family tree type program. I want the nodes to be draggable and I know that jsPlumb can do that for you. However, after the nodes are dragged around and repositioned I want to give the user the ability to save his changes and exact layout will be saved. I will need to get the coordinates of each element and store them in a database and then use that data to recreate the page. How can I do this in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning and retrieve the elements positions with jQuery:

```
var pos = $(yournode).position();
var top = pos.top;
var left = pos.left;
```